# How deep should an API response be

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, api-design

When designing web APIs I've always wondered how deep should entities be presented in the response; meaning if another entity is related to the queried resource whether the top-most entity should include just references of the ID or the complete structure. For example using only id references and then using the id to query the actual entities:

Request

```
GET       HTTP/1.1
/students/<id_student>/exams
```

Response

```
[ 1, 45, 65 ]
```

Request

```
GET    HTTP/1.1 
/exams/1
```

Response

```
 {
    "id": 65, 
    "takenOn": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "score": 95
 }
```

Request

```
GET    HTTP/1.1 
/exams/1
```

Response

```
 {
    "id": 65, 
    "takenOn": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "score": 95
 }
```

---

Or including more details in the first response:

Request

```
GET       HTTP/1.1
/students/<id_student>/exams
```

Response

```
[ 
    {
        "id": 65, 
        "takenOn": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "score": 95
    }, 
    {
        "id": 44, 
        "takenOn": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "score": 85
    }, 

]
```

So in your experience what would be recomended?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While a valid question, it doesn't really belong on SO; https://programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for it.

Comment: I agree with you, how can I migrate it?

Comment: Sorry, not sure, haven't done it before. But post there + delete here surely works.